# How to tell script to look only into a specific folder

Tags: unix

I'm trying to make a recycle bin for UNIX, so I have two scripts. 1 to delete the file and move it to the bin, the other script to restore the file back to its original location.

my restore script only works if the person gives the path to the deleted file.

ex:  sh restore ~/trashbin/filename

How do I hardcode into my script so that I don't need to give the path to the deleted file it should already know to look in the trashbin for the file. My restore script works only when someone calls in the path to the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
rlink=$(readlink -e "$1")
rname=$(basename "$rlink")



function restoreFile() {
rlink=$(readlink -e "$1")
rname=$(basename "$rlink")
rorgpath=$(grep "$rname" ~/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2)
rdirect=$(dirname "$rorgpath")
#echo $orgpath
if [ ! -d "$rdirect" ]
then
  mkdir -p $rdirect
#echo $var
mv $rlink $rorgpath
else
mv $rlink $rorgpath
fi
}


if [ -z "$1" ]
then
   echo "Error no filename provided."
   exit 1
elif [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
   echo "Error file does not exist."
   exit 1
elif [ -f "$rorgpath" ]
then
   echo "File already exists in original path."
   read -p "Would you like to overwrite it? (y/n)" ovr
   if [[ $ovr = y || $ovr = Y || $ovr = yes ]]
   then
   echo "Restoring File and overwriting."
   restoreFile $1
   grep -v "$rname" ~/.restore.info > ~/.restorebackup.info
   mv ~/.restorebackup.info ~/.restore.info
   fi
else
   echo "Restoring file into original path."
   restoreFile $1
   grep -v "$rname" ~/.restore.info > ~/.restorebackup.info
   mv ~/.restorebackup.info ~/.restore.info
fi
```

Comment: Oops! You forgot to post your code. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. We can't fix things that we can't see.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks, I accidently clicked enter to quick.

Comment: @Nabz Could you maybe just `cd` to the trashbin directory at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 0):

When you "remove" the file from the file-system to your trash-bin, move it so that its path is remembered. Example: removing file `/home/user/file.txt` should mean moving this file to `~/.trash/home/user/file.txt`. That way, you'll be able to restore files to the original location, and you'll have auto-complete work, since you can do: `sh restore ~/.trash/<TAB><TAB>`